# From where are the words: "describe" and "it" coming from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing

I saw an application built with Node.js and I don't understand how are the words `describe` and `it` available?

In the browser console `it` is a function and `describe` throws a `ReferenceError`.

I know that they are used for testing.

```
const {assert} = require('chai');
const {jsdom} = require('jsdom');

const parseTextFromHTML = (htmlAsString, selector) => {
  const selectedElement = jsdom(htmlAsString).querySelector(selector);
  if (selectedElement !== null) {
    return selectedElement.textContent;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`No element with selector ${selector} found in HTML string`);
  }
};

describe('User visits index', () => {
  describe('to post an order', () => {
    it('starts with a blank order', () => {
      browser.url('/');

      assert.equal(browser.getText('#deliver-to span'), '');
      assert.equal(browser.getText('#cake-type span'), '');
      assert.equal(browser.getText('#fillings span'), '');
      assert.equal(browser.getText('#size span'), '');
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Probably from one of the libraries imported with `require`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mocha](https://samwize.com/2014/02/08/a-guide-to-mochas-describe-it-and-setup-hooks/) is a testing framework for NodeJS.

[chai](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/introduction-to-testing-in-node-js-with-mocha-and-chai) is an assertion library commonly used with Mocha.

The it() and describe() are from mocha, which you're implicitly importing by `require ('chai')`:

> [Introduction to Testing in Mocha and
> Chai](https://www.thisdot.co/blog/introduction-to-testing-in-node-js-with-mocha-and-chai)
>
> **Mocha Hooks:**
>
> - **it**: Defines a single test.
> - **describe**: Defines a block of tests.

Comment: It is possible that frameworks add new keywords in JavaScript?

Comment: @Marian07 They aren't keywords, they're just function names, like, say, `alert` or how `function foo() {}` would introduce a name `foo`.

Comment: @Marian07 a lot of modern frameworks are moving away from defining global variables and functions - "side effects" - in favour of explicitly exporting parts in their own modular scope. This allows the developer to pick and choose what they want. For user facing code, rogue globals can cause issues and even security issues (used to be able to change `undefined`). Lately, only test-focussed code used to write tests as quickly as possible is the only exception to this, but even then their globals could cause issues elsewhere (which should be picked up by the tests anyway).

Comment: @samthecodingman: Javascript itself never had any concept of "module scope" or "namespace" until fairly recently.  Hence the need for frameworks to invent their own mechanisms and ad hoc conventions.  Or, more commonly, to just pollute the global namespace :(  When Netscape assigned Brendan Eich to write a little scripting engine for their browser in the early 90s, I'm sure he never imagined it would grow into what Javascript/ECMAScript has become today!

Comment: @paulsm4 I'd posit that the module pattern which was very popular was very much the same as "module scope". It is how earlier modularisation was done, too - by enclosing each file in a module and import/requires became input into it, exports were turned into output. ES6 formalised this into the specs but the concept has been around for years before ES6.